# Rolling date monthly option in Adobe Analytics scheduled reports

Tags: adobe-analytics

I need to schedule reports on monthly basis. The reports need to go out on 1st of each month with data from previous month. For reporting, I have selected the preset date option as 'Last Month' with monthly rolling date option. Right now, it says: Rolling date options:   04/01/2017 (rolling monthly) - 04/30/2017 (rolling monthly) which is how it should be. But I am concerned if it considers the varying number of days in a month (30, 31). Can someone confirm when the next set of reports go out on 6/1, whether the date range would be from 05/01/2017 to  05/30/2017 or 05/31/2017?
If it doesn't consider the number of days in a month, is there an alternative to this setup for achieving the same results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Rolling monthly" does just as the name implies. When the date shifts from 4/30 to 5/1, the report will update to April data. When the date shifts from 5/31 to 6/1, the report will update to May data. If on 6/15 you again open the report, it will still be populated with May data, because the month has not yet rolled.